# SPFx Webpart "components" folder?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, sharepoint, spfx, peoplepicker

I'm new in SPFx World, but i have any JS/TS knowledge.

I would like to create a People-Picker Field on my Webpart, but i'm missing a "component" folder with a ts , a scss, and a tsx file in src/webparts . In the Youtube tutorials is this "component" folder with the TypeScript files automatic generated...

YT tutorials folder

[image: 1]

My folders

[image: 2]

I found nothing about ow to create "components folder". I do not want create a new project, but I have tried and I have no idea, how can i get this folder).

Any idea?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I located the same tutorial that you are referring to.

At [this instance](https://youtu.be/ArSB4HtLj3c?t=415), you can see that the Content Creator marks his choice over the `React` bullet answering the question of

> Which framework would you like to use?

What the above does, is that it basically downloads the project with `React` pre-configured for you to use, hence the components folder, where all the react components are to be placed.

You could add `React` to your project after you have initiated it, but since its just a tutorial I would advise simply deleting the project and starting all over again.